# DynamoDB Global Table Backup & Restore

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-backup

I have a global DynamoDB table that is currently replicated across 3 regions (`eu-west-1`, `eu-west-2`, `eu-central-1`).

As part of a PoC piece of work I am looking to use AWS Backup to schedule automated backups, I was wondering what the best practice for this was?

Is it acceptable to take backups of a single region, i.e only schedule the backups for the table in `eu-west-1`? Then when it comes to recovering the table, I can go through the process of first restoring to a non-global table, then adding replica's.

Or is it better practice to ensure all region's tables are backed up at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you backup from a single region (perhaps if you have a primary region for writes use this.

If you restore the DynamoDB table, it needs to create a new DynamoDB table resource. Once this is restored you would then [add your global tables](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/you-can-now-enhance-availability-of-your-existing-amazon-dynamodb-tables-by-adding-global-replicas/) which would replicate the data currently stored in the restored DynamoDB table.

By having multiple backups, you would need to have a strategy to preprocess for any differences between all regions your table exists.